# Sum over multiple count field

Tags: mysql, select, aggregate-functions, jooq

I try to sum mutliple count fields with JOOQ and a MySQL database.

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
int userId = 1;
Field<Object> newField = DSL.select(DSL.count()).from(
                DSL.select(DSL.count())
                        .from(REQUIREMENT)
                        .where(REQUIREMENT.CREATOR_ID.equal(userId))
                        .unionAll(DSL.select(DSL.count())
                                .from(REQUIREMENT) 
                                .where(REQUIREMENT.LEAD_DEVELOPER_ID.equal(userId)))
```

which always returns 2 as newField. But I want know how many times an user is the creator of a requirement PLUS the lead developer of a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "*sum* over multiple count", but that's not what you're doing. You do "*count* the number of counts". The solution is, of course, something like this:

```java
// Assuming this to avoid referencing DSL all the time:
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;

 select(sum(field(name("c"), Integer.class)))
.from(
     select(count().as("c"))
    .from(REQUIREMENT)
    .where(REQUIREMENT.CREATOR_ID.equal(userId))
    .unionAll(
     select(count().as("c"))
    .from(REQUIREMENT) 
    .where(REQUIREMENT.LEAD_DEVELOPER_ID.equal(userId)))
);
```

Alternatively, if you plan to add many more of these counts to the sum, this might be a faster option:

```java
 select(sum(choose()
    .when(REQUIREMENT.CREATOR_ID.eq(userId)
        .and(REQUIREMENT.LEAD_DEVELOPER_ID.eq(userId)), inline(2))
    .when(REQUIREMENT.CREATOR_ID.eq(userId), inline(1))
    .when(REQUIREMENT.LEAD_DEVELOPER_ID.eq(userId), inline(1))
    .otherwise(inline(0))
 ))
.from(REQUIREMENT);
```

[More details about the second technique in this blog post](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/04/20/how-to-calculate-multiple-aggregate-functions-in-a-single-query/)

Comment: Thanks for your help and jOOQ in general! The first solution gets the compiler error: sum(org.jooq.Field<? extends java.lang.Number>) in DSL cannot be applied to (org.jooq.Field<java.lang.Object>). But your second idea works fine. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your nice words. Yeah, you're right. There, I fixed the first example.